# How can I fix the "Expo-cli install error"?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, expo

This is what I am currently receiving when I try to instill.

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...QoQAJQkmBR37svMSvUbRQ'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mattgranado/.npm/_logs/2021-08-31T02_54_24_892Z-debug.log
(base) mattgranado@Matts-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

I did atttempt

```
npm cache clean --force
```

but only got this

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm ERR! Usage: npm cache add <tarball file>
npm ERR! npm cache add <folder>
npm ERR! npm cache add <tarball url>
npm ERR! npm cache add <git url>
npm ERR! npm cache add <name>@<version>
npm ERR! npm cache clean
npm ERR! npm cache verify
```

Then I attempted

sudo npm cache clean --force

to whom which I got the message below.

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
(base) mattgranado@Matts-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install -g expo-cli     
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.0.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mattgranado/.npm/_logs/2021-09-02T02_11_33_424Z-debug.log
```

I would really appreciate any insight on what may be causing these issues.

Comment: Could you try executing the `cache clean` command as an admin?
`sudo npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @JoseManuelBáezSoriano That didn't seem to work